# I am trying to create a subclass of UIImageView in swift to add a simple counter

Tags: swift, class, inheritance, uiimageview, subclass

I am trying to create a subclass of a UIImageView so that I can add a simple counter that will be used to decide whether the image flips horizontally or not when tapped. I read the instructions Apple provides for inheritance and it looks to me as if I'm doing it right. I'm sure its something easy.

Here's the attempt:

```
class flippableImage: UIImageView {

    var flipNumber:Int = 0

}
```

Then I want to be able to change that property when I tap the image. When I go assign flipNumber a value when setting up the object it says that "UIImageView" has no member "flipNumber". Yes, I initialized the subclass and not the parent class. What am I doing?

EDIT to show creation:

```
let imageChosen = UIImage(named: availableImages[NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("image")])
image = Face(image: imageChosen)
image.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2, y: self.view.frame.height/2, width: (faceChosen?.size.width)! * 0.75, height: (faceChosen?.size.height)! * 0.75)
image.userInteractionEnabled = true
image.multipleTouchEnabled = true
backgroundImage.addSubview(image)
backgroundImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
image.center = self.view.center
image.flipNumber = 0 //this doesn't work
```

Comment: Have you set the class for your `UIImageView` as `flippableImage` in Interface Builder?

Comment: The flippableImage is created programmatically, there's nothing representing the chosen image on the storyboard. If i'm understanding correctly.

Comment: Can you please show how you create the `UIImageView`

Comment: Yes, I just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the ViewController, set each image's `tag` property to its counter's value.

Comment: I can't (or don't know how else to approach it), because there are multiple (infinite) images that can be added to the VC. Right now I'm just using one variable in the VC to do what you suggested, but each image needs its own counter to support its own flipping.

Comment: @CodyLucas Could you set each image's tag property with the counter value?

Comment: Yes, I could. I didn't know it had this property, that's very useful. Cheers.

Comment: This would work, but tags are meant to be used for identifying views, such as when calling viewWithTag. Per [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW41): You can use tags to uniquely identify views inside your view hierarchy and to perform searches for those views at runtime.